# Check data update in redux store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have two audio players (mini and main) and when I dispatch pause or play in the mini player I must call the function in the main player. For this, I need to check if the `isplaying` parameter changes.

Does anyone have any idea on how can I achieve this?

In the mini player code:

```js
store.dispatch({type: "PAUSE"})
```

Then in the main player I call the pause function :

```js
const pause = () => {
audio.stop()
}
pause()
```

How do I check if this parameter is changing?

Comment: Can you call pause() in `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method from your main player, assuming there is a status prop which takes the values "playing" and "paused" as values and is mapped to redux store using `mapStateToProps`

Answer (score 0):

you must decorate the target component with the reducer variable:

example:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const Player = ({ status }) => (
   <div>
     {statys === 'PAUSE' ? 'paused' : 'playing'}
   </div>
)

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const { status } = state.PlayerReducer;
  return { status };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Player);
```

PlayerReducer:::

```
export const Types = {
  PAUSE: 'player/PAUSE',
};

const initialState = {
  status: 'PLAYING',
};

export default function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case Types.PAUSE:
      return { ...state, status: 'PAUSE' };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

// Action Creators
export function pause() {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({
       type: Types.PAUSE
    });
  };
}
```

Comment: sorry you dont understand what i need to do , i need to stop audio from another player(mini), i have status and connect player , but i dont know how to check this value changing

Comment: the main and mini player should read the same variable, isn't?
Or pass another function to mini player button that change the main player status.

Comment: In 2 words , when i do dispatch in mini player , i need to call pause/play function in main player.
I have function in mini player that change status in main , but i  cant call function from mini player

Comment: It is not a good pattern doing like this. To follow the redux rules you must observe a variable to react to it.
What about dispatch 2 events ?

Answer (score -1):

I do stop/play on Enter and mainplayer buttons .
and in mini player i write simulate function that on miniplayer buttons click simulate pressing Enter